# Rest API for getting TOTAL team Capacity from Azure Devops

Tags: azure, azure-devops, devops, azure-devops-rest-api

Is there a way to get the capacity of the entire Team from Azure Devops using Rest API.
The current List-Capacity API returns data for each member of the team . 
Is there any way to get the available capacity of the whole team instead of getting the capacity for each member.
List-Capacity API : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/work/capacities/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0

UPDATE:
Feature Suggestion has been created in User Voice Forum to get the capacity of the entire team. Please vote for this suggestion if you're looking for this feature too: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/1004466/api-to-get-the-total-capacity-of-the-team.html

Answer (score 1):

I do not think if there is an API method avaialble, however i came across this method,

```
/**
 * Get a team's capacity
 * 
 * @param teamContext - The team context for the operation
 * @param iterationId - ID of the iteration
 */
public async getCapacitiesWithIdentityRef(
    teamContext: TfsCore.TeamContext,
    iterationId: string
    ): Promise<Work.TeamMemberCapacityIdentityRef[]> {

    const project = teamContext.projectId || teamContext.project;
    const team = teamContext.teamId || teamContext.team;

    return this.beginRequest<Work.TeamMemberCapacityIdentityRef[]>({
        apiVersion: "5.2-preview.2",
        routeTemplate: "{project}/{team}/_apis/work/teamsettings/iterations/{iterationId}/capacities/{teamMemberId}",
        routeValues: {
            project: project,
            team: team,
            iterationId: iterationId
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Sajeetharan. This is current workaround we have planned to go ahead with but we need to get this data for multiple teams and multiple projects. So from performance standpoint it'll be better if we could get the data in a single api call for each team.

Comment: then its not supported as of now

Comment: yeah.. also this will be returning the per day capacity of the team member. How are you getting the total working days in the sprint to calculate the capacity for the sprint..

Comment: @Sajeetharan thanks for this answer, I have been looking for a way to get days off per developer and this is it. Is there a POST version API call for this? I need to update days off field per developer.

Answer (score 0):

> Rest API for getting TOTAL team Capacity from Azure Devops

Sorry for the inconvenience.
As I know there is no such Rest API to get TOTAL team Capacity from Azure Devops. Normally, the functions the **Rest API** provide are **corresponding to** what we can do in **Web Portal**.

[image]

Since the Total Capacity is not supported in either Web Portal or Rest API, you could submit this request on our [User Voice forum](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/index.html) to send your feedback about our product. You can share the idea of the expected Total Capacity feature there and the Product Team would know that.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Lance. I have created a feature Request in User Voice forum.

Comment: Cheers, you can share the link in your question or here so that members who interested in that could vote for you.

Comment: Thanks Lance. I have updated the link in my question.

Comment: You're welcome :) Voted for it just now since I too think the idea is meaningful.